# ftp user for root directories?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I am setting up my Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I want to have an FTP access (I use `vsftpd`), mainly for my apache2 server, so I added a new user to the `www-data` group. I also set up the settings for `vsftpd.conf`, only allowing local users, and `chroot_local_user=YES`.

I changed the home directory of my new user to `/var/www/home`. The permission are 755 (`local_umask=022`).

I can now create files, download them in the `/var/www/home/` directory and can not change to the root directory `/` on purpose for security reasons.

But which strategy can I now use, when I want to change some conf files, download log files and so on, when I only allow the users to stay in their home directory?

Which other security methods are highly recommend, to make my ftp server secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how I would do this, but answering your question anyway:

From `man vsftpd.conf`:

```
chroot_list_enable
      If  activated,  you  may  provide  a list of local users who are
      placed in a chroot() jail in their home  directory  upon  login.
      The meaning is slightly different if chroot_local_user is set to
      YES. In this case, the list becomes a list of  users  which  are
      NOT  to be placed in a chroot() jail.  By default, the file con‐
      taining this list is /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list, but you may  over‐
      ride this with the chroot_list_file setting.

      Default: NO
```

so:

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

and add any user you don't want to be chrooted to that list so you can "change some conf files, download log files and so on".

Comment: okay thank you, but is it overall a good way to go ? I mean then when someone gets access to the account, he can do everything. What is better to do? I mean would it be better to upload/download files in a homedirectory and then with sudo permissions move them on the servers to the folders, where they belong?

I mean it is less comfortable, but probably more save, right?

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @amigo89: What you put in your comment is a [totally different question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) unfortunately.  (and very much off topic here as it asks "what's the best for me?")  For the record: I did not downvote our question; just edited and answered...